# 4D-vector calculations

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

For a 4D vector, how can I calculate any component as a function of the three other components and a magnitude and vice versa?

I want x = f(y, z, i, m) where m is the magnitude of the vector.

Will the function be different if I want to calculate y, z or i?

Is there a universal method for n-dimensional vectors?

Comment: are you taking $m=\|(y,z,i)\|$??

Comment: I would like an orientation in my coordinate system, so that a positive magnitude always orients the same way and a negative magnitude the opposite way. I don't need a single formula, an algorithm will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. You can't even do this in 1D. Suppose I have a one-vector $(x)$ and I tell you its length, $|x|$. You can't tell whether $x$ is positive or negative. But if you're willing to ignore the sign issue, you can do this:

For $u = (a, b, c, d)$, if you're given $a, b, c$ and $\| u\|$ (the magnitude of $u$), you can compute 
$$
d^2 = \| u \|^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
$$
from which you can get $\pm d$.  Similar formulas hold for finding $a$, given $b, c, d$ and $\| u \|$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. You surprised me a little there as I've done this in 2D using sin/cos but then I allowed negative magnitude due to the algorithm I devised (computer programming). So for a magnitude of 4, and 1,2,3 as arguments this would become a = sqr(4^2 - (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2))? Forgive my ignorance. It's at least 13 years since I studied math, and I'm not used to the notation anymore. I'll be using this for a constant positive magnitude of u anyway.

Comment: If you're going to allow negative magnitudes, I'm kind of at a loss -- "magnitude" in mathematics is almost always a hint that the number so described is nonnegative. But I suppose you could say "First let $$d = \sqrt{ \| u \|^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)},$$ and then if the magnitude is negative, you negate $d$." That'd produce all possible 4-vectors from the set of 3-vectors and (positive and negative) magnitudes. In the example you gave, you'd get $a = \sqrt{16 - (1 + 4 + 9)}= \sqrt{2}$; if the magnitude had been $-4$, you'd change $a$ to be $-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, @John. That helps a lot. I've added another question with more constraints. Magnitude is always 1, and a predetermined dimension (the fourth) is always between 0 and 1 inclusive.